# Sockets, xmpp and polling to node.js - performant and server friendly

Tags: node.js, sockets, xmpp, long-integer, polling

i'm building a webapplication and could need some help. The app has got a chat and some news systems. So we have very many writes and need constant update of the information. At the beginning of the project we can't host too many servers because of financial problems. So i wondered, what is the most server friendly way to do this. Which approach needs the minimum of server resources? Can someone help me decide?

Polling - i request new data via ajax every 60 seconds - no two way connection has to be established

xmpp - i recently heard of it - can someone explain in a few sentences if this protocol is performant?

socket.io - a two way connection is established but the server can crash very fast because it just can handle a limited amount of connections

I don't need information on the performance of the approaches. I need to know is it more efficient to do very many single requests on the server or it is better to establish the connection. I've read very many articles on that but my question isn't answered very good yet. Excuse my bad english, not my main spoken language.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not very clear.  What exactly is the issue you anticipate?  Being able to support the required number of write operations or being able to manage multi-users concurrently?

My suggestion is to decide on a reasonable, simple architecture and then fix the bottlenecks as they show up.